# WCF REST Service not accepting JSON in .Net 4

Tags: .net, wcf, json

I've been trying out the StandardEndpoints that were introduced as part of .Net 4 and I'm getting the most peculiar of errors.

My code

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAuthenticator
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "AuthenticateUser", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    AuthPacket AuthenticateUser(string Username, string Password, string DeviceId);
}
```

My web.config

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  </modules>
</system.webServer>

<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  <standardEndpoints>
    <webHttpEndpoint>
      <!--
          Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint
          via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
      -->
      <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
    </webHttpEndpoint>
  </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The exception that is driving me crazy!

```
415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/json' was not 
the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.
```

I can make the problem going away by going back to the .Net 3.5 standard of declaring each service, but, unless I am mistaken, one of the major upgrades in WCF with .Net 4 was it's ability to handle stuff like this. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you tried remove `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest` attribute? How you host the WFC service? Do you use .svc? Which `factory` do you use in the .svc file?

Comment: This is wrapped in a .svc file without a factory defined.

Comment: You should try to use .svc with the factory `"System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"` or include additional section in the web.config which do the same without .svc file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680162/host-wcf-in-mvc2-site/4680617#4680617 for details. Moreover it could help if you include client code (jQuery.ajax or what you use) which follows to the described error message.

Comment: Do you have any progress to solve the problem?

Answer (score 7):

If I read this operation contract correctly, you have defined JSON to be your **response** format - but not your **request** format:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAuthenticator
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "AuthenticateUser", Method = "POST", 
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, 
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    AuthPacket AuthenticateUser(string Username, string Password, string DeviceId);
}
```

Could that be the problem?? What happens if you add `RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json` to your operation contract ??

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAuthenticator
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "AuthenticateUser", Method = "POST", 
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, 
     RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,   <== ADD THIS HERE TO YOUR CODE !
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    AuthPacket AuthenticateUser(string Username, string Password, string DeviceId);
}
```

**Update:** if you're using WCF 4 "out of the box", its protocol mapping will associate the `http://` scheme with `basicHttpBinding`.

To fix this, you need to override the default protocol mapping like this (in your web.config):

Default Protocol Mapping

The answer to this question is simple. WCF defines a default protocol mapping between transport protocol schemes (e.g., http, net.tcp, net.pipe, etc) and the built-in WCF bindings. The default protocol mapping is found in the .NET 4 machine.config.comments file and it looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <protocolMapping>
       <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" />
   </protocolMapping>
```

Now, by default `http://.....` would be mapped to `webHttpBinding`.

(taken from: [A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx) )

Comment: I actually had it that way in an earlier version of the code and it was still kicking back the same problem. The thing that kills me is that when I explicitly declare the services in my web.config everything works.

Comment: @thaBadDawg: well, .NET 4 has those standard endpoints - the default mapping for the `http://` scheme is to use `basicHttpBinding`, however. So unless you've changed that mapping, when you use an `http://somethingoranother.......` address, WCF 4 will default to `basicHttpBinding` - **not** `webHttpBinding`

Comment: When I switch over to use the protocol mapping I get this exception : The message with To 'http://localhost/TokenAuthProvider/Authenticator.svc/AuthenticateUser' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  Getting 500 now instead of 415.